# Read from json file value in a vector

Tags: c++, json

a want to read in a vector of a struct element from a json.
JSON:

> A: [
> { "list" :[
> "a" : 2,
> "b" : 4,
> "c" : 9
> ]
> }

my vector is : std::vector< structE > vec;

> structE{  "a",  "b",  "c" }
>
> ```
>               if (A[i].isMember("list")) // && 
>                   {
>                       auto const list= A[i]["list"];
>                       for (auto i2 = 0u; i2 < list.size(); i2++)
>                       {
>                           vec.push_back(list[i2]["list"]);
>                       }
>                   }
> ```

I have this error:  matching function for call to 'std::vector ::push_back(const Json::Value&)'

Comment: What do you expect `A[i]["list"]` to be? The expression inside the second `[]` evaluates to a pointer to a `const char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have this error: matching function for call to 'std::vector ::push_back(const Json::Value&)'

From your source code, it *appears* that you might be using [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) to handle Json in your C++ code, when dealing with `Json::Value` objects, for basic types such as `int` and `std::string`, you can use [`Json::Value::asInt()`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#c786e35b860b1d700cb3d3e56dd6a235) and [`Json::Value::asString()`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#03ee3d5df576640c93ba683f140828bd) respectively, however, for structs, you need to manually extract the values and construct an object of the struct with those values:

```cpp
struct E {
    int a, b, c;
};

// ...

E createEFromJsonValue(Json::Value const& obj) {
    // Create an object of struct E with values taken from the JSON object
    return {
               obj.get("a", Json::nullValue).asInt(),
               obj.get("b", Json::nullValue).asInt(),
               obj.get("c", Json::nullValue).asInt(),
           };
}
```

Then you can do:

```cpp
// ...
vec.push_back(createEFromJsonValue(list[i2]["list"]));
// ...
```